# Devise - Registration with Paperclip ( missing image )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paperclip

I am currently using paperclip(4.1.1) to upload images to my rails app. Rails(4.0.2), Devise(3.2.2)

I'm also using devise and I am trying to override devise registrations controller so that user can be able to upload images as their avatar, but for some reasons, it's not working, I keep getting "Missing" in my view.

By the way, the `:default_url => "assets/images/small.png"` is not working as well, instead of showing the image, it shows the text `"small"`

Have been Googling but could not find any solution.

Please find below my codes.
Thanks

### Registrations_Controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update
    new_params = params.require(:user).permit(
       :username, :current_password, :password,
       :password_confirmation)
       change_password = true
      if params[:user][:password].blank?
          params[:user].delete("password")
          params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")

          new_params = params.require(:user).permit(:username)
          change_password = false
      end
           @user = User.find(current_user.id)
           is_valid = false
      if change_password
             is_valid = @user.update_with_password(new_params)
        else
             @user.update_without_password(new_params)
      end

      if is_valid
             set_flash_message :notice, :updated
             sign_in @user, :bypass => true
             redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
      else
             render "edit"
      end
  end
```

### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "assets/images/small.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

### user/show.html.erb

```
<h1>USER SHOW</h1>

<div>
    <h3><%= @user.username %></h3>
</div>


<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>

<div>
    <% if @user.posts.any? %>
      <h3>Posts (<%= @user.posts.count %>)</h3>
      <ol>
        <%= render @posts %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have used small size image but you didn't styled it in style of paperclip images add it and it will work for you.

Comment: umm, sorry don't know what you mean, `small.png` (the name of the image is called small)

Comment: Are the images uploaded or not? If the image is uploaded, then you have an issue with your path. If it is not uploaded, then there is a configuration issue, and it doesn't yet matter what you have inside your template.

Comment: For the `default_url`, the image "small.png" is already in 'assets/images/'. And for uploading, the image is not uploaded, so I guess there's something wrong with my `Registrations_Controller.rb`

Comment: has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "assets/images/small.png", that styles did not contains style with small.

Answer (score 3):

The `RegistrationsController` should be defined as below:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController ## Remove :: from the from the front of Devise
```

As you are using Rails 4, you need to permit the parameters that you want to be inserted/updated explicitly. Permit the custom fields that you have added to the Devise model.

In `ApplicationController`, you should have the following code for permitting `avatar`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      ## You can add add other custom fields that you have added to User Model in place of attr1, attr2
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :avatar  << :attr1 << :attr2  ## To permit parameters while User creation
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :avatar  << :attr1 << :attr2 ## To permit parameters while User updation
    end
end
```

The above code will ensure that an `avatar` gets stored for a `User` record.

Also, make sure that the form from where you are uploading an image has `multipart: true`.

For eg:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

Last point, for a `:default_url => "assets/images/small.png"`, make sure you have `small.png` located under `public/assets/images` directory as that's where Paperclip would look for this folder structure.

Comment: thank for the answer, I have added `:avatar` in my `new_params` in my `Registrations_Controller.rb` and it works. But for the default url, I can't get it to use the style `:thumb`, what should I do?

Comment: If you want to specify style as thumb then You should add the default image to "public/assets/images/thumb/small.png" and specify the default_url as "assets/images/:style/small.png"

Comment: I have tried it, but doesn't work, the image is still huge, with no style.

Comment: This is the default image that you are setting which would be displayed if actual image is not found. No styles would be applied to it. You have to take care of the styles for default image.

Comment: So is there a way to add styles to the default images ? Thanks

Comment: Not that I am aware of. If you don't have any tool to do that then just upload the default image for a dummy user as an avatar, copy the generated images(different styles) and save them in the default url path. Then delete the dummy user.